# Send promise with two params

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments, promise

How to pass an additional parameter to `handleFile`?

```
return fs.readFileAsync(path, 'utf8')
    .then(handleFile)
    .then(Process)
    // ...

var handleFile = function (data) {
    var keyVal = {};
    data.split("\n").forEach(function (element) {

// ...
```

I handle `vfile` get data from the `readFileAsync`.

I need it to be something like (pseudo code):

```
return fs.readFileAsync(path, 'utf8')
                .then(handleFile(newParam1,newParam2))
                .then(Process)

                // ...


var handleFile = function (data,newParam1,newParam2) {
```

Comment: The read data will be the last argument to `handleFile`?

Comment: have you tried to use this partial application where you store dost arguments in a closure and then you retrun function which processes just data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for it. It is a way to do partial application and set the execution scope (which shouldn't be important in your case hence `null`)

```
.then(handleFile.bind(null, newParam1,newParam2))

var handleFile = function (newParam1,newParam2, data,) { // ...
```

You can also implement yourself partial application without use of bind, then it will look like:

```
function handleFileWithParams(param1, param2) {
    return function handleFile(data) {
        // ... do stuff
    } 
}

.then(handleFileWithParams(param1, param2))
```

Lastly when you are already using library like lodash, you can use provided function [_.partial](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) which does exactly that.

Comment: the second option might work, but with `bind` wont the `data` parameter be lost if you are binding first parameter to newParam1?

Comment: yes, because of that i proposed another order of parameters in function signature in the provided example (data is used as last parameter)

Answer (score 0):

```
return fs.readFileAsync(path, 'utf8')
         .then(function(data) { 
            // get newParam1, newParam2 here or make sure they are available in closure
            return handleFile(data, newParam1, newParam2); 
         })
         .then(Process)
         ....


var handleFile = function (data,newParam1,newParam2) {
```

Comment: I try it and its not working I got undifend in the handleFile for the all parameters ..

Comment: @kyrylkov: You're missing a crucial `return`

Comment: @Mark `return` added in the answer